# ¿Cómo validar si una varible del tipo Object es null o está vacía?

Tags: c#

Buenas tardes comunidad,

tengo una consulta, estoy tratando de validar si un objeto es null o vacío. Este es mi código:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Net;
using System.Windows.Forms;
namespace ConsoleApplication1
{
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        object hola = new object();



        if (hola == null)
        {
            hola = "hola";
        }

        Console.WriteLine(hola);

        Console.ReadKey();


    }
  }
}
```

He probado con:

```
if(string.IsNullOrEmpty(hola.ToString()))
```

pero no funciona. ¿Hay alguna manera de validarlo?

Comment: hola no tendría que ser del tipo String?

Comment: Lo mismo que el colega @LeviArista... Que estás intentando hacer al inicializar un `object`?

Comment: El valor solo se lo asigno por motivos de prueba, ese no será el valor original, estoy consumiendo un web service que trae como respuesta un object, y necesito almacenarlo en una variable y validar si el objeto venía o no vacío. No le prestes atención al valor :D

Comment: Sólo es por motivo de prueba estimados! Lean la pregunta, no se basen en los valores no pregunté que tipo debía ser, pregunté como validar si el objeto está vacío o no!

Comment: Claro @AlexFernandoVarelaRodriguez, pero ten en cuenta que el IsNullOrEmpty acepta de parametros solo Strings

Comment: Sólo era a modo de intentar algo, ya que no tiene un método count para ver si tiene algún valor, también si valido si es null, no valida nada ya que cuando inspecciono el objeto tiene un valor {object}. Entiendan que lo que quiero es validar si el objeto es o no es nulo, no importa si es un string o no!

Comment: Si, te entendemos, solo queria aclarar esa ultima parte sobre el metodo IsNullOrEmpty, no te preocupes, seguro encontraremos la solucion

Comment: Ahora me pregunto algo.. cuando dices que el _webservice_ devuelve un object... es explicitamente un objeto de tipo object `(System.Object)` o con object te refieres a objeto general `(List, String, Double, etc)`

Comment: explicitamente un objeto de tipo System.Object

Comment: Se me ocurre que podrías tratar de listar las propiedades que - en teoría - debería tener, y de esta forma si el `objeto` viene vacío te lanzara un **0** como respuesta

Comment: Hola. Es muy raro devolver un object en un servicio web. Toda definición de un servicio obedece un esquema y por lo tanto, es una respuesta tipada. Puedes colocar la definición del servicio que consumes?

Comment: @Alex ¿Sabes cual es el tipo "interno" que "envuelve" el Object?, por que si es un JSON si podría decirte cómo hacerlo (deserializando). Podrías llamar al servicio web con PostMan o Fiddler, y ver que tipo de respuesta te devuelve?.

Answer (score 1):

```
object hola = new object();
```

Cuando haces eso, usar el operador new, estas instanciando el objeto, estas creando un espacio en memoria para ese objeto. Asi que su valor nunca sera null

si hubieras hecho esto:

object hola = null;

pues hay seria null, durante la aplicacion puede ser null o no

Answer (score 0):

En el caso que planteas, ¿no te convendría usar un `dynamic` en lugar de `object`? Así podrías tener cualquier objeto serializado y acceder a sus propiedades de la forma `dynObject["propiedad"]`.

Haciéndolo así, puedes realizar la comparación a `null` [de la siguiente manera](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7029699/c-how-to-perform-a-null-check-on-a-dynamic-object#7029733):

```
if (Object.ReferenceEquals(null, hola))
{
    ...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

creo que esta [respuesta](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9323580/how-to-check-object-is-null-or-empty-in-c-net-3-5) , resuelve tu pregunta, primero debes declarar tu objecto como `null`

```
object hola = null;
```

despues pasas tu objecto a string

quedando de esta manera

```
object hola = null;

double d = Convert.ToDouble(string.IsNullOrEmpty((string)hola ) ? 0.0 : hola );
Console.WriteLine(d.ToString());
```

Answer (score -2):

Para empezar, estas declarando mal tu variable, le estas asignando un valor y por tanto nunca obtendrás true en la comparación, en seguida, como ya te han indicado, el método que citas solo funciona con valores de tipo string, anexo un breve ejemplo:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Net;
using System.Windows.Forms;
namespace ConsoleApplication1
{
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        string hola;

        //No hace falta llamar a ToString() porque desde que declaras la variable ya es un string
        if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(hola))
        {
            hola = "hola";
        }

        Console.WriteLine(hola);

        Console.ReadKey();


    }
  }
}
```

Adicional a esto, te recomiendo leer algo de documentación de como se comporta el tipado en C#:

https://docs.microsoft.com/es-es/dotnet/csharp/tour-of-csharp/types-and-variables

Saludos.

Comment: Hay que leer los comentarios de la pregunta.